# Signless Stirling numbers of the first kind with minimum 2 elements

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Let $c_2(n, k)$ be the number of permutations of [n] with k cycles in which each
cycle length is at least two. Find a recursive formula for the numbers $c_2(n, k)$.

**Thought process:**

**Case 1** - element n is in a cycle with one other element

Then we can pair n with any of the n-1 elements and permute the rest into $c_2(n-2, k-1)$

**Case 2** - element n is in a cycle with more than one other element

Then we can permute the other n-1 elements in $c_2(n-1,k)$ ways and place n after any element in a cycle n-1 ways.

**Result**

This would result in

$c_2(n, k) = (n-1)c_2(n-2, k-1) + (n-1)c_2(n-1,k)$

Is this answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Seems correct to me. As a way to check, notice that $$\sum _{k=1}^{n}c_2(n,k)=D_n,$$
the derangement numbers (permutations without fixed points). What you just found is essentially that $D_n=(n-1)(D_{n-1}+D_{n-2}).$
Also, in the literature, you might find them with their generalization as **Associated Factorial numbers.**